# Explaination of Extrapolation from Game Programming Patterns

Tags: physics, rendering, game-loop, movement-prediction, extrapolation

I'm looking for help because there is one thing from the game loop which I don't clearly understand.

I'm in some way of doing implementation of my own 2D game engine based on book „Build Your Own 2D Game Engine and Create Great Web Games" 2nd Edition, and after the game loop there are some sources about doing extrapolation. I've dug some and I know exact both mathematic and implementation-based details of these two (interpolation and extrapolation), but I don't understand that point from [Game Programming Patterns - Game Loop - Stuck in the Middle](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html#stuck-in-the-middle):

> The renderer knows each game object and its current velocity. Say that bullet is 20 pixels from the left side of the screen and is moving right 400 pixels per frame. If we are halfway between frames, then we’ll end up passing 0.5 to render(). So it draws the bullet half a frame ahead, at 220 pixels. Ta-da, smooth motion.

From that quote, I understand that my `render()` function have to parse that `lagTime / millisecondsPerUpdate` (which tells us how much time left we have to the next frame) as a parameter.

But what then? What do I need to do inside `render( lag/ms_per_update parameter )` method, in order to use that `lag/ms_per_update` parameter? How could I even tell the renderer that he have to render it after exact `lag/ms_per_update` value to be sure that it will render value X on the right frame? There are some things inside `render()` that I'm missing or I simply don't understand.

Did you ever implemented extrapolation or maybe you do know this book (Game Programming Patterns) and could you please help me understand what I have to do in the `render()` function in order to properly use that `lag/ms_per_update` parameter to render values at proper frames?

Comment: I've figured it out, the formula is simply:

`Extrapolated_position = position + (velocity * gameLoop.lagTime / gameLoop.millisecondsPerUpdate)`

Comment: To answer your own question, post in the "Your Answer" box below. Answers should never be posted as comments.